# Installed Nvidia drivers and this screen pops up when I turn my PC off

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, cuda

[image]

I'm fairly confident it has to do with the drivers. I needed to use CUDA for PyTorch so I ran `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470`. Everything worked well but this has been popping up since then.

It lasts indefinetely (I realized after more than an hour that it was still on) and the fan skyrockets during this screen.

Comment: So, your PC does not shut down?

Comment: It doesn't, I have to manually press the power button until it shuts down

Comment: Maybe just me but that text is way too tiny to read.